# Make notification in playframework

Tags: scala, notifications, playframework-2.0

I would like to make notification in my website like the ones in facebook. For exemple, in my application I can create an event and I can send invitation to my friend. When he opens his account he can see that invitation in a notification. Is this achievable with playframework ? do I need some other tools to achieve it ?

I'm using `Play 2.0.3` and `Scala`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [Comet sockets](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaComet) or [WebSockets](http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaWebSockets):